# can AIR tell if a USB storage device has been plugged in

Tags: actionscript-3, air

How can I tell from an air app if a USB storage has been plugged in?

is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at the `StorageVolumeChangeEvent` event on `StorageVolumeInfo.storageVolumeInfo`. It will tell you when new volumes are mounted. I'm not sure it's possible to isolate this to (specifically) USB storage.

See [this article for more info](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/exploring_file_capabilities.html#c).

Comment: I believe it is isolated to USB based devices, but have not tested. +1 for raising the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it gets raised if a network volume is mounted

Answer (score 4):

yes it is posible From AIR-2.0 [Mass Storage Device Detection AIR 2.0](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Mass_Storage_Device_Detection_AIR_2_0-16747.html)

Hopes that helps